# How can I select folder/folders to upload in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, file-upload, flutter-web

I am a beginner at developing with flutter web. I couldn't find the library and solution to select folder/folders to upload in flutter web. I can select only file/files, but I couldn't select folder.

Is there any way or solution to select the folder in flutter web?

Thank you very much, your support and help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already **have** a project, **run** this command from a terminal at the location of your flutter  project: `flutter build web`. This populates a **build/web** directory with built files, including an assets directory, which need to be served together.

For more information check the [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) on how to build a web application with flutter.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I mean selecting folder, I could select only one file by using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), but I couldn't select a folder.  I would like to select a folder and upload a folder to drive by using drive API v3. Is there any library for solutions to select folder? Thank you for your support.